# What is a 'known_hosts' file and what does it contains

Tags: ssh, security

I have navigated to **/home/some-user/.ssh/** folder and found a file named **known_hosts**.

What is the purpose of this file and what does it contains?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you googled the term? General questions like this are more suitable for [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/what-is-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-known-hosts-file-for-ssh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of the `known_hosts` file is described quite well in `man ssh`:

> ```
>  ssh automatically maintains and checks a database containing identifica‐
>  tion for all hosts it has ever been used with.  Host keys are stored in
>  ~/.ssh/known_hosts in the user's home directory.  Additionally, the file
>  /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts is automatically checked for known hosts.  Any
>  new hosts are automatically added to the user's file.  If a host's iden‐
>  tification ever changes, ssh warns about this and disables password
>  authentication to prevent server spoofing or man-in-the-middle attacks,
>  which could otherwise be used to circumvent the encryption.  The
>  StrictHostKeyChecking option can be used to control logins to machines
>  whose host key is not known or has changed.
> ```